# Prevent JDeveloper 12c from redeploying servicebus application

Tags: jdeveloper, osb

I have got a servicebus application with 100+ relatively independent projects and am working on one of them. When I'm trying to debug some service the JDeveloper starts to deploy the whole application (I see this in weblogic log). This was not the case earlier and I did not changed any settings recently, at least consciousnessly. Since most of the resources are not available for local env and due to multiple deployment errors the weblogic eventually shuts down. Is it possible to deploy only the required components manually and force JDeveloper to not deploy anything else?